# Getting the Wacom Intuos Comic to Work on Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, usb, tablet, wacom

I recently got my Intuos in the mail.

I immediately downloaded / installed `xf86-input-wacom-0.31.0`, but when I plugged it in nothing picked it up.

- It only shows up under `lsusb` as `ID 056a:033c Wacom Co., Ltd`
- None of my programs relating to drawing tablets are picking it up. Not GIMP, Krita, or the XFCE Mouse/tablet configuration panel.
- I've moved the USB from a hub to a port, but that didn't help.

Is this tablet not supported yet? It's fairly new; I believe it came out this year.

If it isn't supported, when should it eventually be?

Thank you,
-wes

Answer (score 0):

input-wacom 0.30.0 was released today, and has support for your device. You should be able to download the driver at:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxwacom/files/xf86-input-wacom/input-wacom/

and install it according to the instructions at:

http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Input-wacom

Answer (score 0):

If you find it hard to compile the wacom driver, you can find the latest drivers pre-compiled on the ppa (versions 0.31). please follow the instructions here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom/LatestDriver

And report back any issues or errors you may see during the process.